# Transcritical bifurcation for map function

Tags: nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

> Question:
>
> Determine the transcritical bifurcation for $x_{n+1}=\alpha x_{n}\left ( 1-x_{n} \right )^{2}$

I have determined the fixed point to be $x^{\ast}=0$ and $x^{\ast}=1$

Also, for values $\alpha$ such that the region $D \in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ constitute a trapping region, the values of alpha is the set of values in the interval $\alpha \in \left [ 1,\infty \right ]$.

The stability of the fixed point can be determined via the criterion for map stability:

$\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x} \right |_{x^{\ast}} >1 $

or

$\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x} \right |_{x^{\ast}} <1 $

The former indicating the fixed point to be unstable and the latter, stable fixed point.

In this question,

$\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x} \right |_{x^{\ast}=0} =\left | \alpha \right |$ is stable for $\left | \alpha \right | <1$ and unstable for $\left | \alpha \right | > 1$

$\left | \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d} x} \right |_{x^{\ast}=1} =\left | \alpha \right |=0 $. Less than 1 so stable fixed point.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is $1$ a fixed point ?

Comment: $(1-x_n)^2$ term becomes $0$ with $x_n=1$, making it a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{\alpha}(x) = \alpha\,x\,(1-x^2)$. Solving $f_{\alpha}(x)=x$, we find three fixed points at
$$x=0, \:x=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}-1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}, \: \text{ and } \: x=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}+1}{\sqrt{\alpha}},$$ 
at least assuming $\alpha>0$. The last of these is always larger than one and always repulsive; it plays no role in this analysis. When $\alpha=1$, the first two are both equal to zero; this is exactly what we expect at a transcritical bifurcation. Indeed, simple graphs for $\alpha<1$ and $\alpha>1$ show this to be the case:

[image]

Note that the fixed point at zero is attractive for $\alpha<1$, repulsive for $\alpha>1$, and in fact neutral for $\alpha=1$.